# multiple conditions Linq extended

Tags: linq, conditional-statements

I need to consider multiple  conditions to get value.
i mean if all conditions true that must give me a filtered answer.
Or one of them is true,rest are false...
so i need to write all possibilities??
if(a&b&c&d) else if(a&b&c) else if(a&c&d) else if(b&c&d) else if(a&b) else if (a&c)...etc ?? :))) Is there a shorter way to do this?

```
    public List<ProductReqNoDate> GetRequestsQuery(string departmant, int reqStateID, string firstDate, string lastDate, string productName)
    {
        var db = new requestDBEntities();
        bool dp = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(departmant);
        bool pr = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(productName);
        bool tm = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstDate) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastDate);
        bool rs = reqStateID > 0 ? true : false;

        var query = (from r in db.requests
                     select new ProductReqNoDate
                     {
                         departmant = r.departmant,
                         reqNo = r.reqNo,
                         reqDate = r.reqDate,
                         productName = (from p in db.products where p.reqNo == r.reqNo select p.productName).FirstOrDefault()
                     }).ToList();
        if (dp & pr & tm & rs)
        {
            var rState = (from ta in db.reqStates
                          where ta.reqStateID == reqStateID && ta.isActive == true
                          select ta.reqNo).ToList();
            var prName = (from p in db.products where p.productName.Contains(productName) select p.reqNo).ToList();
            DateTime dtfirstDate = Convert.ToDateTime(firstDate);
            DateTime dtlastDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lastDate);

            return query.Where(
                r => rState.Contains(r.reqNo)  //find by Request State
                  && r.departmant == departmant  //find by Departmant
                   && (r.reqDate >= dtfirstDate && r.reqDate <= dtlastDate) //find by Date
                    && prName.Contains(r.reqNo) //Find By Product Name
                    ).ToList();

        }
        else if (dp & pr & tm) { /*return query.Where(...} */}
        else if (pr & tm & rs) { /*return query.Where(...} */}
        else if (dp & pr && rs) { /*return query.Where(...} */}
        else if (dp & pr) { /*return query.Where(...} */}
        //else if ...etc
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add one Where condition at a time

```
public List<ProductReqNoDate> GetRequestsQuery(string departmant, int reqStateID, string firstDate, string lastDate, string productName)
{
    var db = new requestDBEntities();
    bool dp = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(departmant);
    bool pr = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(productName);
    bool tm = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstDate) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastDate);
    bool rs = reqStateID > 0 ? true : false;

    var query = (from r in db.requests
                 select new ProductReqNoDate
                 {
                     departmant = r.departmant,
                     reqNo = r.reqNo,
                     reqDate = r.reqDate,
                     productName = (from p in db.products where p.reqNo == r.reqNo select p.productName).FirstOrDefault()
                 }).AsQueryable();  //AsQueryable is not always needed, but it shouldn't hurt and I don't feel like checking for this example.


    if (dp)
    {
        query = query.Where(q => /*condition*/);
    }

    if (pr)
    {
        query = query.Where(q => /*condition*/);
    }

    if (tm)
    {
        query = query.Where(q => /*condition*/);
    }

    if (rs)
    {
        query = query.Where(q => /*condition*/);
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Isn't this first bringing say all 1 million items from the main table, and then applying the filters in the application?. . . . or if we were to run SQL Profiler, we would see that the database is hit WITH the filters applied and only the rows that meet the filter criteria are returned back to the application (say only 50 rows out of 1 million that meet our criteria)?

Comment: @AshishAnand Because Linq uses deferred execution, the query will not be executed until `.ToList()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can build an expression with [Expression.And](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301748.aspx) like:

```
private Expression<Func<Request, bool>> GetPredicate(FilterDto filter)
{
  Expression<Func<Request, bool>> predicate = r => r.ID == r.ID;

  if (filter.Department.HasValue)
    predicate = predicate.And(r => r.Department == filter.Department.Value);
  if (filter.FirstDate.HasValue)
    predicate = predicate.And(r => (r.reqDate >= filter.FirstDate.Value));
  if (filter.LastDate.HasValue)
    predicate = predicate.And(r => (r.reqDate <= filter.LastDate.Value));

  /* ... */

  return predicate;
}
```

Note: I put `r => r.ID == r.ID` here as first expression, just to have an expression to start with. This snippet does not fully cover your code, but I think it is enough as an example.

Use the expression in `return query.Where(expression).ToList()`.